# What to do with [untagged] questions that are off topic?

Tags: discussion, tags, closed-questions

So as far as I know the untagged tag is automatically added to migrated questions as they have no tags. If this tag is left on a question I could be confusing.

When I was searching the tag I found a question that is tagged with it, link: [How can I learn cursive handwriting?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/178806/how-can-i-learn-cursive-handwriting)

The question:

[image: question]

It was migrated so it was given the untagged tag the closed as off topic. I tried to remove it a sit could be confusing but I couldn’t:

[image: cant’t remove it]

So I was wondering what I should do or what could be done. Could it be deleted or removed by a moderator?

Comment: To do some of the things Nathan said in his answer, you can link the question in [site's main chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24938/language-overflow) so it'd get some attention. Even moderators occasionally visit there. In this case it won't be necessary as you've gone the extra mile with a meta post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All questions need to have at least one tag; edits can never leave a question with zero tags. [untagged](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) is automatically created when necessary when a system action would otherwise leave zero tags, then automatically destroyed again when there are no remaining questions with it.

There are a few ways to handle [untagged](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) questions:

- If it's a lousy question, vote to close and then to delete the question, if you have enough rep to do so
- If it is, again, a lousy question, trigger the roomba to get the question deleted. For this particular case, as it's old and closed, downvoting its score to 0 is enough for the next daily roomba run to wipe it out.
- If it's a decent question, edit it to put a different, relevant tag in.

There's no need to do anything special with [untagged](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) itself; it's just an auto-generated signpost to find questions that would otherwise fall through the cracks.